# Find a recursive definition of this sequence

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I always have some difficulty with problems of this type, and I was wondering if there was a typical trick that makes it reasonable.

Let $W_n$ be the number of words of length $n$ formed with the letters $A$ and $B$ such that

- There are no words that contain sequences of $A$s with length exactly 2
- There are no words that contain sequences of $B$s with length exactly 2 or 3.

Examples of words: $AAAB, ABABABA, ABBBBAAABA$, and of non-words: $AAB, ABBBA$, etc.

These "recursion with constraints" type problems always cause me difficulty. I want to write $W_n = f(W_{n-1}, W_{n-2}, \ldots, W_{n-k})$ for some fixed $k$. I tried to break it into cases based on what the last letter is, so $W_n = A_n + B_n$ where $A_n$ is the number of words of length $n$ that end in $A$ and $B_n$ defined similarly. Then getting recursive definitions for $A_n$ in terms of some $B_{n-k_i}$ and $W_{n-k_j}$ and likewise recursive definitions for $B_n$ produces a whole mess of terms that don't cancel even when you get these $W_{n-11}$ terms showing up. Surely I'm missing the trick?

Comment: Excellent Question!

Comment: @quasi: I think the question is clear now. It means "sequences of $A$s with length exactly $2$, that are not themselves contained in a longer sequence of $A$s." What else could the word "exactly" mean here?

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write down an infinite recursion and then simplify.

Let $A_n$ be the number of such sequences ending in `A`, and $B_n$ be the number of such sequences ending in `B`. We count the empty string in both.

Then, for $n \ge 1$, we have
$$
   A_n = B_{n-1} + B_{n-3} + B_{n-4} + B_{n-5} + \dotsb
$$
because we can add `A` or `AAA` or `AAAA` or `AAAAA` to the end of a string ending in `B`, but not both. So for $n \ge 2$, we have
\begin{align}
A_n - A_{n-1} &= (B_{n-1} + B_{n-3} + B_{n-4} + B_{n-5} + \dotsb) - (B_{n-2} + B_{n-4} + B_{n-5} + B_{n-6} + \dotsb) \\
  &= B_{n-1} - B_{n-2} + B_{n-3}. \\
A_n &= A_{n-1} + B_{n-1} - B_{n-2} + B_{n-3}.
\end{align}
We can do the same thing for $B_n$, except that $B_n$ won't have an $A_{n-3}$ term in the recurrence. For $n\ge 2$, we get
\begin{align}
  B_n - B_{n-1} &= (A_{n-1} + A_{n-4} + A_{n-5} + \dotsb) - (A_{n-2} + A_{n-5} + A_{n-6} + \dotsb) \\
   &= A_{n-1} - A_{n-2} + A_{n-4}. \\
B_n &= A_{n-1} + B_{n-1} - A_{n-2} + B_{n-4}.
\end{align}
This is already enough to make the problem a finite linear recurrence, but we can still try to simplify it further.

---

For $n \ge 1$, we have $W_n = A_n + B_n$, so we have
$$
  W_n = 2W_{n-1} - W_{n-2} +B_{n-3} + A_{n-4}
$$
by adding the two equations. Unfortunately, we still have a mismatched $A$ and $B$ to deal with here.

Expanding $B_{n-3}$ and $A_{n-4}$ out using their recurrences, we get
\begin{align}
W_{n} &= 2W_{n-1} - W_{n-2} + (W_{n-4} - A_{n-5} + A_{n-7}) + (W_{n-5} - B_{n-6} + B_{n-7}) \\
  &= 2W_{n-1} - W_{n-2} + W_{n-4} + W_{n-5} - A_{n-5} - B_{n-6} + W_{n-7}
\end{align}
which again has a mismatched $A$ and $B$, but now in the reverse order. So if we subtract $W_{n-2}$ from both sides, we get
\begin{align}
W_n - W_{n-2} &= (2W_{n-1} - W_{n-2} + W_{n-4} + W_{n-5} - A_{n-5} - B_{n-6} + W_{n-7}) \\&\quad - (2W_{n-3} - W_{n-4} + B_{n-5} + A_{n-6}) \\
&= 2W_{n-1} - W_{n-2} - 2W_{n-3} + 2W_{n-4} - W_{n-6} + W_{n-7}
\end{align}

and the final recursion is $W_n = 2W_{n-1} - 2W_{n-3} + 2 W_{n-4} - W_{n-6} + W_{n-7}$. (This may not fly for small $n$ - in particular, $W_0 \ne A_0 + B_0$ - but for $n> 7$ all the manipulations above are valid.)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this graph will be of assistance:

[image]
You want to count the walks of length $n$ starting from the left-most state and ending up in any of the blue states.

Comment: It's a nice picture! But really, how does it help?

Comment: @TonyK It converts the problem to finding number of walks on a directed graph, so if you'd like you could actually form the adjacency matrix and the answer is given by its powers. Then you could diagonilize this matrix for a formula. On the other hand, you can denote the number of walks that end up in each node by a new variable and form relations among them as other answers have done (maybe not for every node, combine nodes, or maybe some not needed), the picture helps keep track how they go.

Answer (score 2):

Let $w(n)$ be the number of qualifying words of length $n$.

Then $w$ satisfies the recursion 
$$w(n)=2w(n-1)-2w(n-3)+2w(n-4)-w(n-6)+w(n-7)$$
for $n\ge 8$, with initial values
\begin{align*}
w(0)&=1\\
w(1)&=2\\
w(2)&=2\\
w(3)&=3\\
w(4)&=6\\
w(5)&=11\\
w(6)&=18\\
w(7)&=30\\
\end{align*}
The above recursion can be derived as follows . . .

Define functions $a_1,a_3,b_1,b_4$ by

- $a_1(n)$ is the number of qualifying words of length n for which the last constant block is exactly "A".

  $a_3(n)$ is the number of qualifying words of length n for which the last constant block ends with "AAA" (i.e., at least $3$ consecutive occurrences of "A").$\\[6pt]$

  $b_1(n)$ is the number of qualifying words of length n for which the last constant block is exactly "B".

  $b_4(n)$ is the number of qualifying words of length n for which the last constant block ends with "BBBB" (i.e., at least $4$ consecutive occurrences of "B").

Then we get the following linked recursion:
\begin{align*}
w(n)&=
\begin{cases}
1\;\text{if}\;n=0\\
a_1(n)+a_3(n)+b_1(n)+b_4(n)\;\text{if}\;n > 0\tag{eq1}\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
a_1(n)&=
\begin{cases}
0\;\text{if}\;n<1\\
1\;\text{if}\;n=1\\
b_1(n-1)+b_4(n-1)\;\text{if}\;n > 1\tag{eq2}\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
a_3(n)&=
\begin{cases}
0\;\text{if}\;n<3\\
1\;\text{if}\;n=3\\
b_1(n - 3) + b_4(n - 3)+a_3(n-1)\;\text{if}\;n > 3\tag{eq3}\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
b_1(n)&=
\begin{cases}
0\;\text{if}\;n<1\\
1\;\text{if}\;n=1\\
a_1(n-1)+a_3(n-1)\;\text{if}\;n > 1\tag{eq4}\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
b_4(n)&=
\begin{cases}
0\;\text{if}\;n<4\\
1\;\text{if}\;n=4\\
a_1(n - 4) + a_3(n - 4)+b_4(n-1)\;\text{if}\;n > 4\tag{eq5}\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Applying the linked recursion, we get
\begin{align*}
w(0)&=1\\
w(1)&=2\\
w(2)&=2\\
w(3)&=3\\
w(4)&=6\\
w(5)&=11\\
w(6)&=18\\
w(7)&=30\\
\end{align*}
Next, we unlink the linked recursion . . .

Using $(\text{eq}2)$, we can eliminate $a_1$.

Then, using $(\text{eq}4)$, we can eliminate $b_1$.

Then, using $(\text{eq}5)$, we can eliminate $a_3$.

Based on the eliminations, from $(\text{eq}1)$ we get
$$
w(n)=2b_4(n+3)-4b_4(n+1)+3b_4(n)+2b_4(n-1)-3b_4(n-2)+b(n-3)+b(n-4)-b_4(n-5)
$$
for $n\ge 6$, and from $(\text{eq}3)$ we get
$$
b_4(n)=2b_4(n-1)-2b_4(n-3)+2b_4(n-4)-b_4(n-6)+b_4(n-7)
$$
for $n\ge 8$.

Since shifts of $b$ satisfy the same recursion as $b$, and since $w$ is a linear combination of $b$ and shifts of $b$, it follows that $w$ also satisfies the same recursion as $b$, hence we get
$$w(n)=2w(n-1)-2w(n-3)+2w(n-4)-w(n-6)+w(n-7)\tag{eq6}$$
for $n\ge 13$.

We already have the values of $w(n)$ for $0\le n\le 7$.

Applying the linked recursion, we can get the values of $w(n)$ for $8\le n\le 12$, and it can then be verified that $(\text{eq}6)$ fails for $n=7$, but holds for $8\le n\le 12$, hence holds for all $n\ge 8$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rewriting of above work using automaton and generating functions. The associated grammars need to be unambiguous; if not, because of the copies, the numbers obtained will be higher than the right ones.

[image: automaton with four states]
By the second diagram, one may write

$A = x + xC + xD$ where :

$A = a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + ... $is the generating function (or the string index) for words that ends exactly in $0$. We have similar expressions for B, C and D.

Similarly, the other three equations are:

$B = x^3 + xB + x^3C + x^3D $

$C = x + xA + xB$

$D = x^4 + x^4A + x^4B + xD$

Here $x$ stands for $0$ or $1$, $x^3$ covers the bit string $000$; $x^4$ covers the bit string $1111$;

The above (second) system easily solves to the same solution as the first diagram :
[image: automaton with two final states]

here (for example), $x + {x^3 \over 1-x } $ encodes the set { 0, 000, 0000, 00000, ....}

the two equations are

$ A+B = {x-x^2+x^3 \over 1-x } ( C + D + 1 ) $ and

$ C+D = {x-x^2+x^4 \over 1-x } ( A + B + 1 ) $

that easily solves to $ W=A+B+C+D= {2x - 2x^2 - x^3 + 4x^4 -x^5 -2x^6 + 2x^7 \over 1 - 2x + 2x^3 - 2x^4 + x^6 - x^7} $

$= 2+2x +3x^2 +6x^3 +11x^4 +18x^5+30x^6 +50x^7 +85x^8 +143x^9+ 241x^{10} + ...$

The denominator encodes the required recurrence.